# Blazor - Prevent going to login route when user is authenticated

Tags: .net, authentication, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a client Blazor WASM project, which is authenticated with Bearer Token that receives from an API (other project).
I have managed to implement the authentication process using `AuthenticationStateProvider`, and manage the `UI` components to show/hide depending on the authentication state.

One thing I cannot achieve is to prevent user from manually routing to `/login` if the user is Authenticated. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect user when already logged in:

```cs
[Inject] NavigationManager Navigation;

[CascadingParameter] public Task<AuthenticationState> authStateTask {get; set;}

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
  var user = (await authStateTask).User;
  if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    Navigation.NavigateTo("/");    
}
```