# Prevent code from running on my page when I stop it from my MainLayout

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor PWA app with MainLayout and then a bunch of pages. Whenever the user is not logged in, I want to redirect them to the login screen.

It would be great if I could redirect them to the login screen from the MainLayout where I already know that the user is not logged in. I am simply checking a cookie value and then using `NavigationManager.NavigateTo` to move the user to a login page.

However, the initialization code on the individual pages is still running and fails because they assume that the user is logged in.

I can fix it by putting login validation code on every single page. However, I would really like to be able to just checking the login in one place and thereby simplifying all my pages.

So is there a way to do something like this:

```
if (!isLoggedIn)
{
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/login");
    return;
    // Stop any other code from running until the navigation is complete
}
```

Or maybe some other solution to my general issue.

Comment: Cascading authentication state https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73182571/blazor-prevent-going-to-login-route-when-user-is-authenticated/73183634#73183634 +you need the cascading auth state, yes

Comment: I have that already and that means I have to check the auth state on every page and possibly redirect. This is what I am trying to avoid. It's just 2-3 lines so maybe I should just suck it up and copy-paste to every page. Still, I hoped I didn't have to do it.

Comment: Can't you check the Auth State in MainLayout.razor, inside the OnInitializedAsync method, and redirect to login if not authenticated?  AFAIK it would not be possible for users to access other components without MainLayout being initialized.

Comment: Yes and it seems to work for the end-user but the calls in the page that would be shown are still made and fails because the user is not authenticated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AuthorizeRouteView` component to achieve your requirement. Use it inside `App.razor`:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <RedirectToLogin />
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                }
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

And create `RedirectToLogin.razor`:

```
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateTo($"/login");
    }
}
```

`AuthorizeRouteView` component displays an "Authorizing..." message while checking if the user is authorized and only if the check succeeds it loads the page.

[image]

You can customize what is displayed during the authorization check by defining the `Authorizing` template:

```
<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
    <Authorizing>
        @* E.g. show a spinner while authorizing *@
    </Authorizing>

    <NotAuthorized>
         ...       
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeRouteView>
```

More info about `AuthorizeRouteView` component: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#customize-unauthorized-content-with-the-router-component

Comment: That looks good. And do you know for sure that it will not start loading and executing the code in the page while it figures out if the user is authenticated?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to load the page after authorization check is complete and only if user is authorized. Edited my answer with a few more details.

Comment: the documentation you link to seems to suggest that you don't that if statement, and that it's enough to put the RedirectToLogin component in the <NotAuthorized> element

Comment: In the documentation you can find a link to the [blazor project template](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/ProjectTemplates/Web.ProjectTemplates/content/ComponentsWebAssembly-CSharp/Client/App.razor) where you can see that the if statement is included. There is a difference betweeen the user being unauthorized and being unauthenticated. Unauthenticated means the user has not logged in so it redirects to login page. Unauthorized means the user is already logged in but is not allowed to view a specific page.