# Redirect unauthorized user to another page component

Tags: blazor, asp.net-identity, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-authorization, authorize-attribute

In Blazor WASM project I'm using ASP.NET Identity, I want to redirect unauthorized user that do not have the role that allow him access to some pages, I protect the page using:

```
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

It works, Now when the user try to access to the page, He got a blank page, What I want to do is to redirect him to another component page, How can I do that with `Authorize` attribute ?

I tried to redirect the user in `OnInitializedAsync` but it seems the page not loaded to access to this method!

Any help

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73241786/10839134